# No files after send/receive of snapshot between systems

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, ubuntu-20.04, openzfs

I have two separate systems, `prime` and `alt`, on the same network in the same rack:

```
prime 192.168.0.100
alt   192.168.0.101
```

Each system has a zpool running on it, created with the following sequence:

```
> zpool create -O encryption=on -O keylocation=prompt -O keyformat=passphrase <name> /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

The `<name>` of each zpool is respective:

```
prime spool
alt   buck
```

On `prime` there is the following folder structure:

```
/spool
   /AA
     /*
   /BB
     /*
   /test
     /*
```

Here the `/*` represents a variety of elements are underneath the directory.

Additionally on `prime`, there are 6 datasets:

```
> zfs list
/spool
/spool/AA
/spool/AA/Critical_1
/spool/BB
/spool/BB/Critical_2
/spool/test
```

As of this post, `alt` has only the root dataset:

```
> zfs list
/buck
```

And on `prime` I have about 100TB of storage capacity; this is not the case for `alt` which was an older box we decided to turn into a "backup" server for critical data. *Caveat: we are a small support team cobbling things together from antiquated systems with minimum funding*. As such, we only want to send snapshots of the critical data sets to the backup server.

Currently `prime` has the following snapshots

```
> zfs list -t snapshot
spool@20211001
spool/AA@20211001
spool/AA/Critical_1@20211001
spool/BB@20211001
spool/BB/Critical_2@20211001
spool/test@20211001
```

The directories `Crticial_1` and `Critical_2` are something on the magnitude of 40TB combined, so rather than try and build the workflow on these massive sets, the `test` directory was created and only has the following structure:

```
/test
   sample.txt
```

I would like to send the snapshot of this dataset, namely `spool/test@20211001` from `prime` to `alt` and issued the following command:

```
> zfs send -v spool/test@20211001 | ssh root@192.168.0.101 zfs recv buck/test
```

Output dialog appears saying the total size to send is 69KB and then displays a table showing some information, but nothing is put into the table under the columns and then the command line prompt appears for the next command. When I log into `alt` and check, I see the following results:

```
> zfs list
/buck
/buck/test
> zfs list -t snapshot
buck/test@20211001
```

However, when I go into the mount location, there is nothing inside the `test` directory.

What am I doing incorrectly to send over the snapshot/datasets from `prime` to `alt`?